# Joint continuous probability function with variable bounds

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, bivariate

If we have a joint probability density function of the form

[image: ```]

[image]

[image]

I've found c to be 3/2 through setting the double integral of the x bounds and y bounds equal to 1,
Then I tried to find the marginal probability density function of fX through integrating f(X,Y)(x,y) which turned out to be:

[image]

Which works for the x bounds 0 to 1.

However when I solve for fY:

[image]

But I'm not very sure about the bounds of the resulting function, should the bounds stay as x and -x or should I adjust them for the total probability of fY(y) to equal to 1. How do I find the bounds of this marginal density function?

Update: So now I considered the possible values of y which is from -1 to 1
but when I integrate the marginal probability density function of fY from -1 to 1 it does not give me the total probability of 1.

Also, how would I be able to find the probability:

[image]

Where a and b are constants, given the bottom probability is the integral of the marginal probability function from the lower bound to b, I would not get an actual answer without in terms of x if the bounds of the marginal probability function of Y is -x to x, so I assume that I need to adjust the bounds such that they become constant.

Comment: One question at a time: My first objective would be to find the value $c$ that makes this a density function. Can you sketch the region of support of $(X,Y)?$ When $x = 1,$ what are possible values of $y?$ When $x = 1/2?$ When $x=0?$ // After you have made some progress, please edit your question to show what you have done.

Comment: I've found c to be 3/2, the region of support is the area between the lines y = x, y = -x, 0 < x < 1, possible values of y is from -1 to 1 since x is from 0 to 1.

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag.

Comment: And draw a graph of the domain where $f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)>0$, it will help in finding the range of possible values of $Y$.